# Selection sorting. not getting the required output

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, stdvector, selection-sort

What is wrong with this code? Not getting the right output.

```
void selectionSort(vector<int>& arr, int n)
{   
       for(int i = 0; i < n-1; i++ )
       {   
           int min = arr[i];
           for(int j = i+1; j < n; j++)
           {
               if(arr[j] < min)
                   min = arr[j];
           }
           swap (min, arr[i]);
       }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the local variable `min` in the swap where you needed to use the vector element.

```
swap(arr[index_min], arr[i]) // `index_min` is the index of the current min value.
```

Comment: thanks. I made a horrendous mistake -_-

Answer (score 1):

The variable `min` stores the value of the element `arr[i]`

```
int min = arr[i];
```

After this call of the function `swap`

```
swap (min, arr[i]);
```

the value stored in the element `arr[i]` can be lost. You need to swap values of two elements of the vector.

Also the second parameter of the function only confuses.

```
void selectionSort(vector<int>& arr, int n)
```

For example the vector can have less elements than the value of `n`.

Either declare the function like

```
void selectionSort(vector<int>& arr );
```

and use the member function `size()` to determine the number of elements in the vector.

Or declare the function like

```
void selectionSort( std::vector<int>::iterator first, 
                    std::vector<int>::iterator last );
```

Or declare the function as a template function that uses forward iterators.

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

void selectionSort( std::vector<int> &v )
{
    for ( std::vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i < v.size(); i++ )
    {
        auto min_i = i;
        for ( auto j = i + 1; j < v.size(); j++ )
        {
            if ( v[j] < v[min_i] ) min_i = j;
        }

        if ( min_i != i ) std::swap( v[i], v[min_i] );
    }   
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = { 9, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0 };

    for ( const auto &item : v )
    {
        std::cout << item << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    selectionSort( v );


    for ( const auto &item : v )
    {
        std::cout << item << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

The program output is

```
9 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 9
```

Or if to use iterators then the function can look the following way as shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

template <typename ForwardIterator>
void selectionSort( ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last )
{
    for ( ; first != last; ++first )
    {
        auto min_it = first;

        for ( auto next = std::next( first ); next != last; ++next )
        {
            if ( *next < *min_it ) min_it = next;
        }

        if ( min_it != first ) std::iter_swap( min_it, first );
    }   
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = { 9, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0 };

    for ( const auto &item : v )
    {
        std::cout << item << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    selectionSort( std::begin( v ), std::end( v ) );


    for ( const auto &item : v )
    {
        std::cout << item << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Again the program output is

```
9 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 9
```

Using iterators you can sort any subrange of a vector.

Instead of the inner for loop in the function definition above you can use standard algorithm `std::min_element`. In this case the function will look the following way

template

```
template <typename ForwardIterator>
void selectionSort( ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last )
{
    for ( ; first != last; ++first )
    {
        auto min_it = std::min_element( first, last );

        if ( min_it != first ) std::iter_swap( min_it, first );
    }   
}
```